# Ler XML através do Python

Tags: python, xml, django

preciso pegar dados num arquivo XML de outro domínio, inicialmente fiz um js, tive de abortar.

Pensei em ler os arquivos através de .py  dentro do meu projeto Django
Em carater de teste Tentei algo mais um menos assim:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(file=urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.2.57:8010/data/camera_state.xml'))
root = tree.getroot()
root.tag, root.attrib

for elem in tree.iter():
    print elem.tag, elem.att
```

Não consegui chegar na estrutura que precisava, a saida do meu teste.py, esta mais ou menos assim:

```
CameraState {}
Cameras {}
Camera {'Id': '1'}
State {}
Camera {'Id': '2'}
State {}
Camera {'Id': '3'}
State {}
Camera {'Id': '4'}
State {}
```

Essa é a estrutura do XML no servidor externo, como posso extrair os dados usando o ElementTree para chegar nessa estrutura original? abaixo

```
<CameraState>
    <Cameras>
        <Camera Id="1">
            <State>NO_SIGNAL</State>
        </Camera>

        <Camera Id="2">
            <State>OK</State>
        </Camera>
    </Cameras>
</CameraState>
```

Preciso obter esses dados para posteriormente salvar essas informações numa tabela, mas essa parte é tranquilo.

Abraço

Comment: aparentemente, o que a funcao iter() faz a travessia por todos os elementos, e a saída realmente é a que você teve. a estrutura está certa. se você quer apenas os filhos do CameraState, e não passar por todos os elementos, faça sem o iter():for elem in tree:

Answer (score 2):

o root já está na estrutura que você quer, é uma lista encadeada, mas se voce usa o iter(), o resultado será todos os elementos. se você quer a hierarquia, percorra então como uma hierarquia:

```
print(root.tag,":")
for cameras in root:
    print("---|",cameras.tag,":")
    for camera in cameras:
        print("---|---|",camera.tag,":", camera.attrib)
        for state in camera:
            print("---|---|---|",state.tag,":", state.text)
```

a saída será:

```
CameraState :
---| Cameras :
---|---| Camera : {'Id': '1'}
---|---|---| State : NO_SIGNAL
---|---| Camera : {'Id': '2'}
---|---|---| State : OK
```